# Calling Type.GetRuntimeMethod on an interface with a generic method returns null

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, windows-runtime

I am using reflection in one of my C# projects: it is Portable Class Library  targeting Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

In that project, I have an interface named IMyInterface that has a method DoSomething with a generic parameter TGenericObject. I also have a class named MyClass. At one point, I need to look up the method DoSomething in the specified interface by reflection. So, I am using the GetRuntimeMethod method from the Type class with the actual parameter's type, which is MyClass in my example.

Please, keep in mind that the example I am providing here is just to highlight the problem I am facing. The reality is that the interface IMyInterface and the class MyClass are in another project.

Here's the deal: I was expecting the GetRuntimeMethod to return the MethodInfo of the DoSomething method, but it did not: null is returned.

Is there something easy that I am missing to find the DoSomething method from the IMyInterface or do I have to get hands dirtier?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething<TGenericObject>(TGenericObject myGenericObject);
}

public class MyClass
{ }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClassInst = new MyClass();

        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof (IMyInterface).GetRuntimeMethod("DoSomething", new [] { myClassInst.GetType() });
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyClass` doesn't implement  `IMyInterface`. Can this be the problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( MyClass is not meant to derive from IMyInterface. The MyClass instance is the parameter needed to call the generic DoSomething method.

Comment: I don't see anything that implemets `IMyInterface` in your sample. How you expect to find  a "concrete" runtime method?

Comment: I don't think the implementation of IMyInterface is needed at this point  because what I am trying to find by reflection is the MethodInfo of the  DoSomething method as declared in the interface :S But, let's say you add an implementation of IMyInterface called MyInterfaceImpl and in the Main method you replace typeof(IMyInterface) by typeof(MyInterfaceImpl). Unfortunately, what you get is still the same result: methodInfo is null. (BTW, the sample I provided compiles :) )

Comment: I know it compiles, But Since you are here it is clear that what you think is not correct :)

Comment: Obviously :) I tried what you proposed (and I thank you for your suggestion) but I got the same result. What I do not know is why the GetRuntimeMethod is not able to find a method with a generic parameter, whether it is called on an interface or even a class.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Kzrystof GetRuntimeMethod is not supposed to resolve overloads, formally you don't have such method declared so it's not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to code my own extension method that actually do what I expected from GetRuntimeMethod method. What bothers me is that I still do not understand why the GetRuntimeMethod method provided by .NET returns null in my sample.

Here is the incomplete class that temporarily fixes my issue. This is a very naive approach but it is a starting point. There are a lot of things missing in that class but at least, it is an answer that allows me to go on.

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Looks for the method in the type matching the name and arguments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <param name="methodName">
    /// The name of the method to find.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="args">
    /// The types of the method's arguments to match.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    /// Thrown if:
    ///     - The name of the method is not specified.
    /// </exception>
    public static MethodInfo GetRuntimeMethod(this Type type, string methodName, Type[] args)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(type, null))
            throw new NullReferenceException("The type has not been specified.");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("methodName", "The name of the method has not been specified.");


        var methods = type.GetRuntimeMethods().Where(methodInfo => string.Equals(methodInfo.Name, methodName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

        if (!methods.Any())
            return null;    //  No methods have the specified name.

        if (methods.Count == 1)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = methods.Single();
            return IsSignatureMatch(methodInfo, args) ? methodInfo : null;
        }

        //  Oh noes, don't make me go there.
        throw new NotImplementedException("Resolving overloaded methods is not implemented as of now.");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds out if the provided arguments matches the specified method's signature.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodInfo"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool IsSignatureMatch(MethodBase methodInfo, Type[] args)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!ReferenceEquals(methodInfo, null), "The methodInfo has not been specified.");


        //  Gets the parameters of the method to analyze.
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

        int currentArgId = 0;

        foreach (ParameterInfo parameterInfo in parameters)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(args, null) && currentArgId < args.Length)
            {
                //  Find out if the types matchs.
                if (parameterInfo.ParameterType == args[currentArgId])
                {
                    currentArgId++;
                    continue; //  Yeah! Try the next one.
                }

                //  Is this a generic parameter?
                if (parameterInfo.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter)
                {
                    //  Gets the base type of the generic parameter.
                    Type baseType = parameterInfo.ParameterType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;


                    //  TODO: This is not good v and works with the most simple situation.
                    //  Does the base type match?  
                    if (args[currentArgId].GetTypeInfo().BaseType == baseType)
                    {
                        currentArgId++;
                        continue; //  Yeah! Go on to the next parameter.
                    }
                }
            }

            //  Is this parameter optional or does it have a default value?
            if (parameterInfo.IsOptional || parameterInfo.HasDefaultValue)
                continue; // Uhum. So let's ignore this parameter for now.

            //  No need to go further. It does not match :(
            return false;
        }

        //  Ye!
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```